# LeetCode problem-Remove Duplicates from Sorted Array

Tags: c#, arrays, dictionary

I am wondering why my solution showing wrong answer in LeetCode? Can someone help what went wrong in my solution?

```
public class Solution {
    public int RemoveDuplicates(int[] arr) {
          var dic = new Dictionary<int,int>();
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length - 1; i++)
            {

                if (!dic.ContainsKey(arr[i]))
                {
                    dic.Add(arr[i], i);
                }
            }
            if (!dic.ContainsKey(arr[arr.Length-1]))
            {
                dic.Add(arr[arr.Length - 1], dic.Count-1);
            }
            return dic.Count;
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: ` if (!dic.ContainsKey(arr[arr.Length-1]))` you don't need this `if` block. `i < arr.Length - 1;` this is not correct. it should be `i < arr.Length;`

Comment: do you have to use a dictionary or can you utilize a list?

Comment: Hint: if your list is already sorted, then duplicate values will all be next to each other.

Answer (score 0):

First, I am not familiar with "Leetcode", but as far as logic goes-->You could try something like this instead. Using a list and a similar for loop, if the list doesn't contain the element of the array in the method argument, then it adds it. If it already contains it, it does nothing. Then, the method returns the list as an array.
**edited per comments

```
public static int[] RemoveDuplicates(int[] arr)
{
    List<int> numList = new List<int>();
    int counter = 0;
    numList.Add(arr[0]);

    for(int i = 0; i < arr.Length;i++)
    {
        if (arr[i] != numList[counter])
        {
            numList.Add(arr[i]);
            counter++;
        }
    }
    return numList.ToArray();
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int[] nums = { 1, 1, 2,2,2,2,2,4,4,4,4,6,6,7,7,7,8,8,8 };

    int[] filtered = RemoveDuplicates(nums);

}
//returns an array with elements [1,2,4,6,7,8]
```

Comment: If the input list is already sorted, which is the case here, then doing it this way is very inefficient. Duplicates are already next to each other: just keep only the first value you encounter.

Comment: writing a method assuming that all inputs will already be sorted is not ideal. This is just for a general case, but I understand what you mean.

Comment: The question is literally titled "Remove Duplicates from Sorted Array". I think it is safe to assume the array is sorted here.

Comment: you right, you right.

Answer (score 0):

my solution :

```
    public static int[] RemoveDuplicates(int[] arr)
    {
        HashSet<int> result = new HashSet<int>();

        foreach (var item in arr)
        {
            result.Add(item);
        }
        
        return result.ToArray();
    }
```

Explain : hashset not store duplicate value